# how to get values of selected rows in data grid view and store as Dictionary data structure

Tags: c#, datagridview

Window form contains a grid view along 
with check box column ,which is populated with data.I want to get values of checked/ selected rows in data grid view and store the values as a form of dictionary data structure for further operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should go the other way round. Instead of tying to extract data from your `DataGridView` and store it in some collection, first place your data in a collection and then [**bind**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial) this collection to the DataGridView.

- First create a data class with properties for all your DataGridView columns.
- Then create an `ObjectDataSource`.
- Then fill your data in a `List<DataClass>`.
- Finally assign this list to grid through the [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) property.

From now on, when edits are made, the changes will automatically be written back to your data objects.

You can do this for binding to `Forms` as well. This saves you all the effort of formatting and assigning your data to controls and then (after edits have been made) read the controls and convert the strings back to typed data.